# Linux device drivers: bind and unbind

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

I came across the LWN article *["Manual driver binding and unbinding"](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/)*, where it explains how to use the `sysfs` interface to dynamically bind and unbind drivers in Linux. Where exactly in the kernel code is this interface implemented? I assume this is shared across the whole kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is implemented [here in `drivers/base/bus.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/drivers/base/bus.c#L205).

The function that gets called when you write to `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind` is `bind_store()`, which gets the string passed from userspace and uses it to find the appropriate device. Then checks if the driver declares support for the device in its id table, and if so it binds it to the device. Similarly, [`unbind_store()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/drivers/base/bus.c#L182) in the same file handles unbinding through `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`.

The functions you are interested in are probably these:

- [`bus_find_device_by_name()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/include/linux/device/bus.h#L173) from `linux/device/bus.h`
- [`bus_find_device()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/drivers/base/bus.c#L322) from `linux/device/bus.h`
- [`device_driver_attach()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/drivers/base/dd.c#L1063) from `linux/device.h`
- [`device_release_driver()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/drivers/base/dd.c#L1258) from `linux/device.h`

You can see if a device matches a specific driver through [`driver->bus->match()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/include/linux/device/bus.h#L90).

Note that `device_driver_detach()` (used in `drivers/base/bus.c` to implement unbinding) is not exported, use `device_release_driver()` instead.